# graph of a function, measure theory, real analysis

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

the graph of continuous function $f:\Bbb{R}\to \Bbb{R}$ has measure $0$.

the graph of measurable function $f:\Bbb{R}\to \Bbb{R}$ is measurable.
it can also be shown it has measure 0:
[The graph of a measurable function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/117886/the-graph-of-a-measurable-function)

But could you show me an example of:

1. (noncontinuous) function with graph of positive measure?
2. (nonmeasurable) function which has nonmeasurable graph?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think the graph of nontrivial solution of Cauchy equation has nonmeasurable graph.

Comment: I found this:
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/35606/lebesgue-measure-of-the-graph-of-a-function
But the answer is difficult for me.

Comment: Any answer to this question will be like that; there are no nice examples one can "see".